# Create API Gateway with {} in path

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I need to create API Gateway with `{}` in path: `/from/{date1}/to/{date2}`

but was able to generate only following: `/from/date1/to/date2`

This is what I need:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api" {
  name = "my_api_gateway"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "api" {
  path_part   = "api"
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.root_resource_id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "from" {
  path_part   = "from"
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.root_resource_id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "date1" {
  path_part   = "date1"
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.from.id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "to" {
  path_part   = "to"
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.date1.id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "date2" {
  path_part   = "date2"
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.to.id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "method" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.date2.id
  http_method   = "POST"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "api" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id

  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode([
      aws_api_gateway_resource.api.id,
      aws_api_gateway_method.method.id,
      aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda.id,
    ]))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "api" {
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.api.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  stage_name    = "dev"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "example" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  stage_name  = aws_api_gateway_stage.api.stage_name
  method_path = "*/*"

  settings {
    metrics_enabled = true
    logging_level   = "INFO"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "response" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.date2.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method
  status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.response.status_code

  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda
  ]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.date2.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method
  status_code = "200"

  response_models = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, are there any errors with this code? If so, it's probably the best to add them to the question.

Comment: No errors. But I updated my question with actual/expected results.